# Cloning Small Slow SSD to Large Fast SSD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, clone

I am trying to see if there is a way that I can clone my small boot drive SSD(SSD1) to my other SSD which is 1TB and is much faster (SSD2). My problem is that when I got SSD2, I didn't think to just install Windows on it and I instead installed all my games on SSD2. I have about 500GB worth of games on SSD2. Unfortunately now, I am finding that SSD1 is really slowing down my Windows so I want to clone SSD1 into a partition of SSD2 so I can just boot from SSD2. All the options I have seen involve wiping SSD2 clean and then cloning Windows on it. I would normally backup SSD2 but I don't have any drive to backup 500GB of files to. Is there anything I can do here?

Comment: You would be far safer for all scenarios if you had a backup drive; that way you could experiment with impunity. We get at least two questions a day here that could be best answered, "replace from your backup".

Answer (score 1):

Every solution that we would suggest would carry some risk of losing the disk(s),
since disk operations are risky in nature.
Although I can suggest the following procedure, I do not recommend doing it
without a full backup, or at least you need to accept the possibility that
a total reinstall would be required.

The procedure is as follows:

1. Prepare a boot media for Windows 10
2. Disconnect SSD1 and connect SSD2 in its place, using the same disk connectors
3. Install Windows to SSD2
4. Connect SSD1 with the disk connectors previously used for SSD2
5. Boot into the Command Prompt
6. Find the drive-letters of the two disks and use the `copy` command to
   copy all the files from SSD1 to SSD2, starting from the root `\`
7. Reboot.

In case of any failure, you could most likely just return to the
original configuration, and have just wasted some space in SSD2.

In case of success, you might need to modify how the games are being run,
since they will now reside on `C:`, rather than on `D:`.